# How can I use an element as filter source?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I would like to use an element I defined in the `<defs>` as source input for another element's filter.

My goal is to do a Composite with two forms: the one I apply the filter on and another one.

I was expecting this to work, but it doesn't:

```
<defs>
  <rect id="shape1" (...) />

  <filter id="f1">
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="#shape1" operator="xor" />
  </filter>
</defs>
<circle id="shape2" filter="url(#f1)" (...) />
```

How can I replace `in2="#shape1"` in order to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly reference a shape in a filter's "in" property like this. You have to first pull it in with an

```
<feImage .... result="myShape1">
```

and then reference it as in2="myShape1". IE10 has different behavior than webkit in how they treat in-document elements pulled into a filter in this way. Webkit/blink are spec compliant in that they treat any x,y declared in feImage to be an *additional transform* to the x,y coordinates of the original element. IE10 seems to *replace* the x,y coordinates of the original element with the new coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's not supposed to be used with a browser, no problem with compatibility. But thanks for the info!